# Help Installing Linux W/ Ubuntu onto a Usb stick to boot from another computer From a Linux Machine

Tags: boot, windows

Im tryng to boot my computer with Linux w/ Ubuntu through a Usb stick/flash drive. I know how to do it from a windows computer but not from another linux machine...Help?

Answer (score 0):

To create a bootable Flash Drive in Ubuntu [look here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

[A little more in depth](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Is this what you are looking for?

Also, if you mean that you are trying to boot from the flash drive. Then there should be some settings in the bios to change the order of boot devices. ( F9, F12, ESC ) On boot up.